# web3js cant send transaction

Tags: transactions

I have a problem. Few days ago, I could send transaction but now I can't.I don't understand why.I hope someone will help me. Just get hash, no receipt, no confirmation.
[image]

**geth**

```
geth --fast --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,web3,net,personal --ws --wsapi db,eth,web3,net,personal --wsport 8546 --wsorigins "*"
```

Comment: Are you deploying to a private test net or to a public network like mainnet/ropsten/rinkeby? Can you show us the code from `test.js`?